# Ubuntu 22.04 installation failed every time

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, thinkpad, 22.04

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad t460p with 8GB RAM and 128GB Lexar SSD. I am trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 on it by following [this](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/04/install-ubuntu-2204-step-by-step/) guide.

After the installation completes when I restart the system, it displays *reset system* on the top left corner and restarts itself. I tried multiple times with the same results. I also tried the Boot-Repair method. Previously I had Zorin OS 16.1 and it was working great.

Comment: How did you make the installation USB? Did you [verify the `.iso`](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview) beforehand? 

Comment: Are you dual booting with Windows?

Comment: Can you get to the GRUB menu? If you had Ubuntu installed before 22.04, try booting to an earlier kernel via the GRUB menu. If this is your first Ubuntu, try booting to Recovery Mode via the GRUB menu. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Using bleana etcher i made bootable usb,from ubuntu official website i download iso file.

Comment: No i am not booting with windows.it is one and only linux(ubuntu)

Comment: No i can not get GRUM menu.

Comment: Someone locked comments for 15 hours.Sorry for late commenting.

Answer (score 1):

Enter the Bios/UEFI menu, then disable secure boot and delete all secure boot keys.
Retry the process then.

[Disable Secure boot](https://itsfoss.com/disable-secure-boot-windows/)

Comment: I’m fighting the same problem. No UEFI settings in the Bios but UEFI is supported by this older Gateway laptop. I had Linuxfx on it which is based on Lubuntu 22.04 but trying to do a fresh install the lighter Kubuntu. Single boot, goes to GRUB on install, then nothing after I make a choice. If I wait ten or fifteen minutes the Kubuntu logo appears and goes away, then nothing again. 1TB hard drive but only 2GB RAM which is the maximum available. AMD64, ATI Radeon XPress 200M.

Answer (score 0):

On my Dell 15-7568 I could not boot on UEFI mode to install Ubuntu 22.04. I used Legacy mode and defined `/` and `/home` properly in the installation, so as not to destroy Windows 10 which was installed on half the HDD. After the install, I enabled UEFI mode, booted into Windows and installed Grub2Win. Nothing else worked for me.